# Jquery how to add a class containing two dashes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I have a simple page  which toggles the visibility of departments, with a nice icon to show whether or not it is visible.
I am using font-awesomes icons "fa-eye" and "fa-eye-slash"

Problem is when using addClass jquery ignores the second "-" making

```
$(this).addClass("fa-eye-slash")
```

Add the class "fa-eye".

Its very strange and i've never encountered something like this with jquery. Please can someone assist me on how to overcome/work around this.

heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m5cdpnhk/

Thanks

Comment: Try toggle class instead of the ifs, it seems to work for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/m5cdpnhk/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `if` conditions which run one after the other.

If the first `if` runs, then one of the things it does is `$(elm).addClass('fa-eye-slash');`.

The second `if` condition is `if ($(elm).hasClass("fa-eye-slash"))` so if the first `if` runs then the second will *always* run.

You need an `else` statement.

```
    $(elm).addClass('fa-eye-slash');
} else if ($(elm).hasClass("fa-eye-slash")) {
    $(elm).removeClass("fa-eye-slash");
```

Comment: Think I need more coffee, was messing around with this for over an hour without realising that!

Answer (score 1):

Add an **else** option (the problem is the two if without the else in this case)

```
$(".box-body ul li i").click(function () {
    var elm = $(this);

    if ($(elm).hasClass("fa-eye")) {
          $(elm).removeClass("fa-eye"); 
          $(elm).css("color", "red");
          $(elm).addClass('fa-eye-slash');
    }else{
         //if ($(elm).hasClass("fa-eye-slash")) {
              $(elm).removeClass("fa-eye-slash");
              $(elm).addClass("fa-eye");
              $(elm).css("color", "green");
         //}
    }
});
```

or **toggle** the class

```
.red:before{
  color:red
}
.green:before{
    color:green;
}


$(".box-body ul li i").click(function () {
   var elm = $(this);
   $(elm).toggleClass("fa-eye").toggleClass("red");
   $(elm).toggleClass("fa-eye-slash").togglesClass("green");               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why your code don't work but try this :

```
$(".box-body ul li i").click(function () {
        var elm = $(this);

                if ($(elm).hasClass("fa-eye")) {
                    $(elm).removeClass("fa-eye"); 
                    $(elm).css("color", "red");
                    $(elm).addClass('fa-eye-slash');
                }else{
                    $(elm).removeClass("fa-eye-slash");
                    $(elm).addClass("fa-eye");
                    $(elm).css("color", "green");
                }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5cdpnhk/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have done mistake.you have to place "else if" at second if condition.

```
if ($(elm).hasClass("fa-eye")) {
                    $(elm).removeClass("fa-eye"); 
                    $(elm).css("color", "red");
                    $(elm).addClass('fa-eye-slash');
                }
                else if ($(elm).hasClass("fa-eye-slash")) {
                    $(elm).removeClass("fa-eye-slash");
                    $(elm).addClass("fa-eye");
                    $(elm).css("color", "green");
                }
```